# Find a character from a string from its back

Tags: javascript

How can I find the position of last "/" from a url from back using JavaScript.

Like : If my URL is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask then how can I find the position of last '/' (before the 'ask') from its back

Comment: Use for loop to check each character, if found save its index to counter and overwrite the counter everytime the character '\' is found.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma have a look at the answers to this question, you are emulating a builtin function!

Comment: @collapsar Yes I saw. Still calling a function may be easier, but writing the code is more efficient. Take any example of inline functions in c++.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma You are aware of the differences between JS and C++? the different code translation techniques involved? Have you actually profiled your code ? And why do you believe that using `charAt` wouldn't involve a function call? Given the current state of JS maturity you can be almost sure that a single `lastIndexOf` call will vastly outperform any explicit iteration of the string characters, even if I assume that the iteration is translated into a single chunk of native machine code without fn calls.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [String.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
var pos = url.lastIndexOf("/"); //returns the position of last occured /
```

> The `lastIndexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the last occurrence of the specified value, or -1 if not
>   found.

Answer (score 0):

```
var aa='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ';

Console.log(aa.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/fosezami/1/edit)

http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-find-index-string/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
complete.lastIndexOf(part)
```